# How to move the user account/Profile 2 information from the content region to a sidebar region

Tags: 7, users, theming

On the "My Account" page i.e. /user, the account and Profile 2 information is by default residing in the content region. I would like to move everything to the right sidebar region. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this ?

I am using [Bartik](https://www.drupal.org/project/bartik)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a View (show Users) with display "block" and add User:ID as Context Filter. For the Context Filter set "When the filter value is NOT available" to "provide default value - User ID from URL". Add all user fields that you would like to output to your view. Created Views block will then be listed on you Blocks page (structure > blocks). Once the block is there, you can drag it into the sidebar region.

If you need to remove user profile fields that are rendering in content region by default or override them, you can do so by overriding "modules/user/user-profile.tpl.php" - copying it into your theme's template folder and replacing  the line that renders user profile - `<?php print render($user_profile); ?>` with the desired content.

[Page Manager Existing Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/pm_existing_pages) + [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) is another convenient method of changing the layout of user profile. This method will work in combination with existing layout regions.

Comment: I got up to contextual filter part, but after that I don't see any profile related fields in the "add fields" list. Any ideas?

Comment: edited the answer with more details -check it out

Comment: I only got the profile fields when I chose "show Profile", instead of "show Users". Is that how it is meant to be?

Comment: yes, If you created a view with contextual filter of User:ID it will only show fields for one user when the context filter is available - means, only when you are viewing single user profile.

Comment: I am now using "show Users" for the Views block. The User fields are showing fine, but the Profile fields are empty (I added the User: Profile relationship). I also made sure the profile fields were filled with values. How do I solve this?

Comment: make sure each profile2 field uses the corresponding User:Profile relationship in field settings

Comment: Turns out the Profile fields were empty because I left the profile types checkboxes unchecked on the User:Profile relationship config . page. Thanks for you help.