# Move a taxonomy page field to a different region

Tags: theming

I currently have taxonomy pages using a custom image field, **field_icon**, which by default displays in my content region.

How would I go about moving this field display to a different region (in my case the **header** region)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach this in UI, Twig or PHP:

**UI**

You can create a View (show Taxonomy Terms) with display "block" and add "Term ID" as Context Filter, see this example for Users: [How to move the user account/Profile 2 information from the content region to a sidebar region](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186989/how-to-move-the-user-account-profile-2-information-from-the-content-region-to-a/187048#187048)

**Twig**

Install [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) and place the field in a twig template:

```
{{ drupal_field('field_name', 'taxonomy_term') }}
```

**PHP**

Prepare the taxonomy term entity in a preprocess hook, see [print custom image field for taxonomy page (page--taxonomy.html.twig) template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229009/print-custom-image-field-for-taxonomy-page-page-taxonomy-html-twig-template/229045#229045)

Comment: Thank you, this helped me out perfectly. I used the Twig Tweak path, your links for UI and PHP were very helpful as well!